# Failed to fix broken packages in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kernel, patch

I'm trying to run this command: `sudo apt install -f`

I have this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  snapd-login-service
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 4 not to upgrade.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up ros-kinetic-librealsense (1.12.1-0xenial-20190607-170900-0800) ...

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Running the pre_build script:

dkms: Pre-build script started...

Downloading kernel sources...
Reading package lists...
Picking 'linux-signed-hwe' as source package instead of 'linux-image-4.15.0-55-generic'
Need to get 12.4 kB of source archives.
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main linux-signed-hwe 4.15.0-55.60~16.04.2 (dsc) [1,829 B]
Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main linux-signed-hwe 4.15.0-55.60~16.04.2 (tar) [10.6 kB]
dpkg-source: info: extracting linux-signed-hwe in linux-signed-hwe-4.15.0
dpkg-source: info: unpacking linux-signed-hwe_4.15.0-55.60~16.04.2.tar.xz
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file 'linux-signed-hwe_4.15.0-55.60~16.04.2.dsc' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
Fetched 12.4 kB in 0s (237 kB/s)
grep: drivers/media/usb/uvc/uvc_driver.c: No such file or directory
INFO: No Intel RealSense(TM) cameras are currently supported.
Patching uvcvideo sources...
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/drivers/media/usb/uvc/Makefile b/drivers/media/usb/uvc/Makefile
|index c26d12fdb8f4..d86cf22155d1 100644
|--- a/drivers/media/usb/uvc/Makefile
|+++ b/drivers/media/usb/uvc/Makefile
--------------------------
File to patch: Picking 'linux-signed-hwe' as source package instead of 'linux-image-4.15.0-55-generic'
Picking 'linux-signed-hwe' as source package instead of 'linux-image-4.15.0-55-generic': No such file or directory
File to patch:
```

Please help!

Comment: errr... what happens if you type `sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt update` then try again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it.

I pressed Ctrl + C to stop the process and then I saw:

```
File to patch: ^Cdpkg: error processing package ros-kinetic-librealsense (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script was interrupted
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-kinetic-realsense-camera:
 ros-kinetic-realsense-camera depends on ros-kinetic-librealsense; however:
  Package ros-kinetic-librealsense is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ros-kinetic-realsense-camera (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-kinetic-turtlebot-bringup:
 ros-kinetic-turtlebot-bringup depends on ros-kinetic-realsense-camera; however:
  Package ros-kinetic-realsense-camera is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ros-kinetic-turtlebot-bringup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-kinetic-turtlebot:
 ros-kinetic-turtlebot depends on ros-kinetic-turtlebot-bringup; however:
  Package ros-kinetic-turtlebot-bringup is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ros-kinetic-turtlebot (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-kinetic-turtlebot-teleop:
 ros-kinetic-turtlebot-teleop depends on ros-kinetic-turtlebot-bringup; however:
  Package ros-kinetic-turtlebot-bringup is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ros-kinetic-turtlebot-teleop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ros-kinetic-librealsense
 ros-kinetic-realsense-camera
 ros-kinetic-turtlebot-bringup
 ros-kinetic-turtlebot
```

I used: `sudo dpkg --purge <the packages which could not be processed>`

And then: `sudo apt install debian-keyring linux-source-4.15.0`
(4.15.0 is the kernel version)